# What are all the valid ways to represent an IP6 address w/ an email

Tags: ipv6

Given user@1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8 how many different ways can this be represented in an unnormalized way.

I found in a test suite for emails [Dominic Sayers email test suite](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/results.php) the following email. The host was the part that interested me particularly the wrapped of the number notations with "IPv6["

"first.last@[IPv6:::12.34.56.78]";

Are the brackets only allowable for emails or ip6 addresses as well ?

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 literal addresses should be expressed in brackets for URLs, e.g. `http://[::1]`

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt

This follows through for email addresses, e.g. `root@[127.0.0.1]` or `root@[IPv6:::1]`.

It's to avoid the case of say `dead:beef:1` attempted to be resolved as the DNS host `dead`.

Comment: I tried to read the rfc but its so long and confusing. Is there a definitive simple one page list that gives example of valid emails or hosts. If the list also included invalids and why that would be great.

Comment: Is it allowed to include [IPv6:AAAA .... in regular hosts ? the ipc6 bit ? i dont understand why its necessary as the [] is enough to differentiate.

Comment: also words like "should" are bad - is that should as in required or optional ?

Comment: @mP: yes the IPv6: prefix does appear completely redundant in purpose for SMTP.

Comment: you didnt actually say if brackets are required or optional in urls ?